# Android - Intent Sniffing

Tags: android, android-intent

We were having security related discussions on a project, and there was a point raised saying that passing unencrypted data via Intents might potentially be dangerous.

I wrote a few samples, and have listed my findings below.

1. Implicit Intents - It is dangerous to send sensitive data across Implicit Intents, since someone else can use the same Intent Filter that you have and intercept your data.
2. Explicit Intents within the Application - It is safe to send data via Intents. I wrote an Intent Sniffer based on what Mark Murphy lists here, but was unable to intercept intra-application Intents. Using 'New Task' and 'Single Task' flags did not change anything.
3. Explicit Intents to other Applications - I was able to sniff Intents when I launched the other app using the 'New Task' flag.

Please let me know if it looks okay, or if anyone else has alternate opinions. Is there any other scenario I should be testing ? Have I missed out on something ?

Comment: If an `Intent` is sent from your app, it's open for anyone to read.  Inside the app, it's not.  Simple!  An `Intent` is just a fancy wrapper for IPC.

Comment: Also make sure to set exported to false on any activity/service you don't want outside apps to call-  such as activities that are meant to be behind login screens.  Otherwise people can call it directly and bypass your security.

Comment: "I was able to sniff Intents when I launched the other app using the 'New Task' flag" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: "Otherwise people can call it directly and bypass your security" -- for most components, that's true only if the component has an `<intent-filter>`. Components are exported by default with an `<intent-filter>`, not exported by default without an `<intent-filter>`. Particularly for activities, do *not* have an `<intent-filter>` and *also* be not-exported, as you may mess up choosers. And you always want to put `android:exported` on your `<provider>` to be `true` or `false`, as the rules for the default for providers have changed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was able to sniff the following intent thought it was explicit and not implicit when the New Task flag was there, but was unable to sniff it when the New Task flag was not there -        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @Abhinav: Please define "sniff" in this context.

Comment: For the record, and those ending up here looking for ways to sniff intents, there is an open source intent intercept application:
https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept